# making code change that affects the method name.

Tags: svn, version-control, refactoring

I need to make a code change where the change I am making will affect the meaning of the method name.

What would be the best practice to handle such changes? Keeping the old name and and make the changes inside? Or rename the method? Or any other best practice?

Note, we use sub version.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing an API change.

If you need to be backward compatible try writing a new method, deprecating the old method and calling the new method from inside the old (now deprecated) method. Give a time frame to the developers to remove the deprecated method (weeks, months, next version...).

If you don't need to be backward compatible just change the method name. All the code that uses old method will FTBFS and should be changed.

Comment: Thanks Diego. It was helpful that you mentioned backward compatibility